# trouble with saving and printing data with arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a slight bit of trouble with saving data into arrays.  Most of the code works as required, but what I'm having trouble doing is saving the data, such as deposits, withdrawals, transfers, into an array for them all to be printed out at the end.  Two main problems are occurring.
1. Either nothing has been entered (which is completely acceptable) and then random digits are being output. 2. If something has been entered during a loop, such as a deposit, and then the user decides to enter another deposit before the loop is finished, the output will only be the last entry (whereas I want it to be two separate outputs).  I can't seem to think of a way around these problems so any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//global variable for the overdraft
float OVERDRAFT = -1000;


//function to determine interest rate for users deposit
//return the interest rate to be used in the total() function
float interest(float money)
{
float int_rate;

if (money < 0 && money >= -100)
{
    int_rate = 1.2f;
}
else if (money >= 0 && money < 100)
{
    int_rate = 1.1f;
}
else if (money >= 100 && money < 200)
{
    int_rate = 1.5f;
}
else if (money >= 200 && money < 500)
{
    int_rate = 1.8f;
}
else if (money >= 500)
{
    int_rate = 1.9f;
}
else if (money < -100 && money >= -500)
{
    int_rate = 1.4f;
}
else if (money < -500 && money >= -1000)
{
    int_rate = 1.8f;
}
return int_rate;
}


//function to calculate final amount with interest applied
//uses previous interest() function to calculate final amount by multiplying them together
//if the amount is less than -1000 (overdraft) then the OVERDRAFT value of -1000 is returned
//else, returns the normal amount
float total(float x)
{
float int_func;
int_func = interest(x);
float amount = x * int_func;
if (amount < OVERDRAFT)
{
    return OVERDRAFT;
}
else
{
    return amount;
}

}


//function that checks if user enters an amount greater than 0
//returns an integer dependent on this
//this is used in main function to determine if money can be added to the account (0 means yes, -1 means no)
float add_money(float *Account, float Amount)
{
if (Amount > 0)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return -1;
}
}
float take_money(float *Account, float Amount)
{
if (Amount > 0)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return -1;
}
}


//function to be used for the transfer section in the main function
//finds out if users input (multiplied by interest) is positive
//if it is, 0 is returned which can be used later
float transfer(float y)
{
float int_func;
int_func = interest(y);
float amount = y * int_func;
if (amount >= 0)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return -1;
}

}


//creates a sentinel while loop so that user can exit it if they press 0, or reloops if they enter any other number
float main(void)
{
float sentinel = 1;
while (sentinel != 0)
{
    //asks the user to enter amount they wish to deposit in both main and savings accounts
    //asks the user how many months they want to simulate (3 months with a starting deposit of £50 will result in £55, £60.50, £66.55)
    float deposit, add, take, savings, tran;
    int count, amount, answer;
    float x, dep[51], withd[51];
    float m_to_s[51], s_to_m[51];

    printf("Initial deposit for your main account:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &deposit);
    while (deposit < OVERDRAFT)
    {
        //while loop to make sure user enters positive number for main account
        printf("ERROR: You have an overdraft limit of \x9C%.0f.\nPlease enter a greater initial deposit:\n", (OVERDRAFT* -1));
        scanf_s("%f", &deposit);
    }
    printf("Initial deposit for your savings account:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &savings);
    while (savings < 0)
    {
        //while loop to make sure user enters positive number for savings account
        printf("ERROR: Please enter a positive value:\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &savings);
    }
    printf("Amount of months to simulate:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &amount);
    while (amount <= 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Please enter a value greater than zero:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &amount);
    }

    //for loop with a switch statement to allow user to choose option from main menu
    //user can deposit money, withdraw money, transfer money, and move to the next month with interest applied from the menu
    for (count = 1; count <= amount; count++)
    {
        printf("\nPlease choose one of the below options:\n");
        printf("1: Deposit money (Main account only)\t");
        printf("2: Withdraw money (Main account only)\n");
        printf("3: Transfer money\t\t\t");
        printf("4: Balance next month (with interest)\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &answer);
        while (answer <= 0 || answer >= 5)
        {
            //while loop to ensure user chooses one of the 4 options
            printf("\nPlease choose one of the below options:\n");
            printf("1: Deposit money (Main account only)\t");
            printf("2: Withdraw money (Main account only)\n");
            printf("3: Transfer money\t\t\t");
            printf("4: Balance next month (with interest)\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &answer);
        }

        //main menu
        switch (answer)
        {
            //option 1 to deposit more money
            //adds money to the account if 0 was returned in add_money() function
            //errors given if -1 was returned in add_money() function
        case 1: printf("\nYou chose to make a deposit\n");
            printf("Amount to deposit:\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &dep[count]);
            add = add_money(&x, dep[count]);
            while (dep[count] <= 0)
            {
                //while loop to ensure user enters a value greater than 0
                printf("ERROR: Please enter a value greater than zero:\n");
                scanf_s("%f", &dep[count]);
            }
            if (dep[count] > 0)
            {

                deposit = deposit + dep[count];
                printf("Main account balance: \x9C%.2f.\n", deposit);
                //reduces count by 1 so that it outputs correctly at end
                count -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("ERROR: You entered an invalid amount.\n");
                count -= 1;
            }break;



            //option 2 to withdraw money
            //reduces count by 1 so that the program doesn't end sooner than the user wanted
        case 2: printf("\nYou chose to make a withdrawal\n");
            printf("Amount to withdraw:\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &withd[count]);
            take = take_money(&x, withd[count]);
            while (withd[count] <= 0)
            {
                //while loop to ensure user enters value greater than 0
                printf("ERROR: Please enter a value greater than zero:\n");
                scanf_s("%f", &withd[count]);
            }

            if (withd[count] > 0)
            {
                //sets deposit variable to a new value according to the users input (may be reverted back in the if statement if it goes over overdraft)
                deposit = deposit - withd[count];
                if (deposit < OVERDRAFT)
                {
                    //reverts the recentl deposit variable as it will not be possible as the user will go over the overdraft
                    printf("ERROR: You can't withdraw that much as you will go over your overdraft limit\n");
                    deposit = deposit + withd[count];
                    count -= 1;
                    break;
                }
                else if (deposit > OVERDRAFT)
                {
                    printf("Main account balance: \x9C%.2f.\n", deposit);
                    count -= 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("ERROR: You entered an invalid amount\n");
                count -= 1;
            }break;

            //option 3 to transfer money from one account to another
        case 3: printf("\nYou chose to transfer money\n");
            printf("Please choose an option:\n");
            printf("1: Transfer from Main account to Savings account\n");
            printf("2: Transfer from Savings account to Main account\n");
            int option;
            scanf_s("%d", &option);
            while (option < 1 || option > 2)
            {
                //while loop to ensure user chooses one of the two options
                printf("Please choose an option:\n");
                printf("1: Transfer from Main account to Savings account\n");
                printf("2: Transfer from Savings account to Main account\n");
                scanf_s("%d", &option);
            }
            //switch inside a switch
            switch (option)
            {
            case 1: printf("\nYou chose to transfer money from your Main account to your Savings account\n");
                printf("Please enter how much to transfer:\n");
                scanf_s("%f", &m_to_s[count]);
                tran = transfer(m_to_s[count]);
                while (m_to_s[count] <= 0)
                {
                    //while loop to ensure user enters a value greater than 0
                    printf("ERROR: Please enter a value greater than zero:\n");
                    scanf_s("%f", &m_to_s[count]);
                }

                //if statement that will be run if user enters value greater than 0
                if (m_to_s[count] > 0)
                {
                    savings = savings + m_to_s[count];
                    deposit = deposit - m_to_s[count];
                    if (deposit >= OVERDRAFT)
                    {
                        //prints out both balances of accounts after the transfer
                        printf("\nMain account balance %.2f\n", deposit);
                        printf("Savings account balance: %.2f\n", savings);
                        count -= 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("ERROR: You can't transfer that much as you don't have a large enough overdraft on your Main account\n\n");
                        //if user enters an incorrect amount (because overdraft is reached), variables are restored so that end output is correct
                        savings = savings - m_to_s[count];
                        deposit = deposit + m_to_s[count];
                        count -= 1;
                    }

                }break;

            //transfer money from savings to main
            case 2: printf("\nYou chose to transfer money from your Savings Account to your Main account\n");
                printf("Please enter how much to transfer:\n");

                scanf_s("%f", &s_to_m[count]);
                tran = transfer(s_to_m[count]);
                while (s_to_m[count] <= 0)
                {
                    //while loop so ensure user enters a value greater than 0
                    printf("ERROR: Please enter a value greater than zero:\n");
                    scanf_s("%f", &s_to_m[count]);
                }

                //if statement that will be run if user enters a value greater than 0
                if (s_to_m[count] > 0)
                {
                    //adjusts balances using users entered value (these variables may be reverted in the else statement if the savings go lower than 0 as there is no overdraft)
                    savings = savings - s_to_m[count];
                    deposit = deposit + s_to_m[count];
                    if (savings >= 0)
                    {
                        //prints out current balances
                        printf("\nMain account balance: %.2f\n", deposit);
                        printf("Savings account balance: %.2f\n", savings);
                        count -= 1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //error if user tries to transfer too much money out of their savings account because there is no overdraft
                        printf("ERROR: You can't transfer that much as you don't have an overdraft on your Savings account\n\n");
                        savings = savings + s_to_m[count];
                        deposit = deposit - s_to_m[count];
                        count -= 1;
                    }break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("ERROR\n\n");
                    count -= 1;
                }break;

            }break;

            //option 4 to move onto the next month (with interest applied to both accounts)
        case 4:
            deposit = total(deposit);
            savings = total(savings);
            printf("\nYou chose to show account balances (with interest) for the next month\n");
            printf("Month %d Main account balance: \x9C%.2f.\n", count, deposit);
            printf("Month %d Savings account balance: \x9C%.2f\n", count, savings);

        }
    }

    for (count = 1; count <= amount; count++)
    {
        //sting array
        //prints out transactions
        //NOT WORKING CORRECTLY

        printf("\nDeposit %d: %.2f\n", count, dep[count]);
        printf("Withdrawal %d: %.2f\n", count, withd[count]);
        printf("Transfer Main to Savings %d: %.2f\n", count, m_to_s[count]);
        printf("Transfer Savings to Main %d: %.2f\n", count, s_to_m[count]);
    }


    //if user enters 0, while loop is broken
    //if user enter anything other than 0, loop reloops
    printf("\nTo terminate program, enter '0'.\n");
    printf("To run program again, enter any other number.\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &sentinel);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: TR;DR. You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: That looks like one of the longest posts I've read recently. Just reduce to the **minimal** and complete code to show your problem.

Comment: while producing that MCVE,  be sure to consistently indent the code.  In general, this means indent after EVERY opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.   Doing such consistent indenting will make the code much easier to read/understand.  For the same goals, separate code blocks (if, else, do...while, while, switch/case) by a blank line and separate functions by 2 blank lines.

Comment: regarding this function: `float interest(float money)`,  the parameter `money` is a 'float', so why are you comparing it to integer values rather than float values?

Comment: when coding, follow the following principal.   Only one statement per line, only one variable declaration, at max, per statement

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile.  when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ).   The posted code causes the compiler to output many warnings.   Please fix the code.

Comment: Note: `float main(void)` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: 1) `for (count = 1; count <= amount; count++) { ... scanf_s("%f", &dep[count]);` is suspicious.  I would expect `count = 0; count < amount`  2) No test that `amount` is in a legitimate range.  3) Specifying inputs used would help.

Answer (score 1):

the code is long and really hard to go through but if I did understand it corectly you need to:

1. Initialize all the variables. Set them to zero or something accaptable for you.
2. you are using `dep[count]` but you always do `count -= 1;` after that. Try to look at that.